# Why is SQLAlchemy not picking up on changes to the database?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Apologies in advance but I've not been able to replicate the issue in a full MRE. Instead I've tried to illustrate with some 'dummy' code. Here goes...

I have a query that returns some records as a list something like:

```
list_ids = session.query(TableName.id_).filter(TableName.number.__le__(5).all()
```

I then iterate over this list in parallel with a second, parallel friendly `session_factory` session that I create using a class called `DataAccessLayerParallel()`. I then re-run the original query to check the result:

```
def my_parallel_func(list_id):
    dal = DataAccessLayerParallel()
    my_record = dal.session.query(TableName).filter_by(id_=list_id).scalar()
    # Does some stuff to change TableName.number field in my_record
    dal.session.commit()
    # Does some more stuff to close the session

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(my_parallel_func, list_ids)

list_ids = session.query(TableName.id_).filter(TableName.number.__le__(5).all()
```

The problem I have is that on the second run of original query I get back exactly the same result even though I've changed the records such that I shouldn't.

I've checked the database straight after the `executer.map()` finishes and the records have definitely changed. I've also extracted the SQL for the second run of the original query before the `.all()` and this returns the correct result with the changed records. Finally, if I re-run all the code again then the first time the original query runs then it returns the correct result with the changed records.

I can't work out how this could be happening as clearly the `.commit()` has worked so any ideas on why the second run of the original query isn't picking up the changes?

Comment: Your `session` holds a transaction open until you either commit or rollback. In MySQL the default isolation level is REPEATABLE_READ, where the name should hint at what will happen. You must `session.commit()` or `session.rollback()` to begin a new snapshot.

Comment: @IljaEverilä - thanks for the pointer. Just to confirm - I'll need to add a `session.commit()` between `executer.map()` and the query being run for a second time?

Comment: That is correct.